# Issue with Axis 1.4 (Could not load [META-INF/services/org.apache.axis.EngineConfigurationFactor)

Tags: java, spring-boot, axis, java-11

I have a Spring-boot project run with JDK 11, need import an external lib to do some functions, this lib is dependency to Axis 1.4.
When I Run as >> Java application, it's ok. But when I run by "mvn spring-boot:run". Have exception

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Illegal access: this web application instance has been stopped already. Could not load [META-INF/services/org.apache.axis.EngineConfigurationFactory]. The following stack trace is thrown for debugging purposes as well as to attempt to terminate the thread which caused the illegal access.
at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.checkStateForResourceLoading(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1383)
at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.getResource(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1036)
at org.apache.commons.discovery.jdk.JDK12Hooks.getResources(JDK12Hooks.java:134)
at org.apache.commons.discovery.resource.DiscoverResources$1.getNextResources(DiscoverResources.java:124)
at org.apache.commons.discovery.resource.DiscoverResources$1.getNextResource(DiscoverResources.java:98)
at org.apache.commons.discovery.resource.DiscoverResources$1.hasNext(DiscoverResources.java:84)
at org.apache.commons.discovery.resource.names.DiscoverNamesInFile$1.getNextClassNames(DiscoverNamesInFile.java:226)
at org.apache.commons.discovery.resource.names.DiscoverNamesInFile$1.getNextClassName(DiscoverNamesInFile.java:209)
at org.apache.commons.discovery.resource.names.DiscoverNamesInFile$1.hasNext(DiscoverNamesInFile.java:196)
at org.apache.commons.discovery.resource.names.NameDiscoverers$1.getNextIterator(NameDiscoverers.java:122)
at org.apache.commons.discovery.resource.names.NameDiscoverers$1.hasNext(NameDiscoverers.java:105)
at org.apache.commons.discovery.resource.classes.ResourceClassDiscoverImpl$1.getNextResource(ResourceClassDiscoverImpl.java:116)
at org.apache.commons.discovery.resource.classes.ResourceClassDiscoverImpl$1.hasNext(ResourceClassDiscoverImpl.java:103)
at org.apache.axis.configuration.EngineConfigurationFactoryFinder$1.run(EngineConfigurationFactoryFinder.java:120)
at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at org.apache.axis.configuration.EngineConfigurationFactoryFinder.newFactory(EngineConfigurationFactoryFinder.java:113)
at org.apache.axis.configuration.EngineConfigurationFactoryFinder.newFactory(EngineConfigurationFactoryFinder.java:160)
at org.apache.axis.client.Service.getEngineConfiguration(Service.java:813)
at org.apache.axis.client.Service.getAxisClient(Service.java:104)
at org.apache.axis.client.Service.<init>(Service.java:113)
```

Please help me resolved it.

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem. When I restart the server, this error does not occur.